# How can I know when someone's finished watching a video on an Android app?

Tags: java, android, video, android-activity

This is my first question on Code Project.

I'm making an Android app. In one of the activities I play videos. When one video ends, the second is supposed to start.

At the moment this part of my Java file plays one video:@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_watch);

```
    VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

    String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);

    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

    vidView.start();
}</pre>
```

When this video ends I'm supposed to play the second one. I will probably number the videos so that I can sequence through them.

But my question is:
How can I know when someone's finished watching the first video? I don't allow controls (like forwarding) so that they don't skip any videos. But I don't want them to move on to the second video by closing the app halfway through the first video, for example. So, how can I know when they've finished the first video, and how can I dynamically change the video being played (e.g. video5.mp4)?

Comment: for FSM sake did you at least read VideoView documentation ? this class doesn't have much setOnXXXX methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook onto the [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) of the `VideoView`

> Register a callback to be invoked when the end of a media file has
>   been reached during playback.